# If $f(x)\ge g(x)$, is $f'(x)\ge g'(x)$?

Tags: derivatives

We choose any function for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Also, $x$ needs to be positive at all times. Lets say that $f(x)=45x^2$ and $g(x)=15x^2$.

We can say that $f(x)\ge g(x)$, if $x\ge 0$. So the condition is $\color{blue}{x\ge 0}$.

The derivatives are $f'(x) = 90x$ and $g'(x) = 30x$. We can also state that

$$f'(x)\ge g'(x)$$

with the same condition: $\color{blue}{x\ge 0}$.

I've been wondering. If $f(x)\ge g(x)$, does that mean that $f'(x)\ge g'(x)$ with the same conditions for the variables used in the function.

Comment: The question is vague. If you choose $g=0$ and $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ then you have $f \ge g$, but $f'(0) = -2 < g'(0)$.

Comment: There are many good examples posted at this point, but to clarify I believe your "$x \geq 0$" was intended to mean that the inequality holds for all such $x$, yes?  It doesn't change the truth of the claim.

Comment: Fortunately it holds that if $f\geq g$ then $\int f\geq \int g$ with some conditions on $f$ and $g$ and several flavors of $\int$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $g(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1 + \sin(x)$. Then $f(x) \geq g(x)$ and $g'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ but $f'(\pi) = -1$.

Answer (score 3):

No, for a nonconstant example consider $f(x) =  2 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} $ and $g(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$.  Then $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$, but
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$
$$g'(x) = e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Abstract answer: suppose $f_1,g,f_1',g'$ bounded, $f_1'\not\ge g$. Add a constant to $f_1$ s.t. $f=f_1+M\ge g$. But as the derivative of a constant is zero, $f'=f_1'\not\ge g$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=2e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$. Then $f(x)>g(x)>0$ for all $x$, but $f'(x)<g'(x)$ for all $x$

Answer (score 1):

No. $f(x) = x, g(x) = x^2$ on $\left(1/2,1\right)$.

Indeed, $f(x) - g(x) = x- x^2 = x(1-x) > 0$,

and $f'(x) = 1 < 2x = g'(x)$ since $x > 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Just choose $\;f\;$ monotone ascending and $\;g\;$ the other way around...For example,

$$f(x)=\cos x\;,\;\;g(x)=\sin x\;,\;\;x\in \left[0,\frac\pi2\right]\;$$

then $\;f(x)\ge g(x)\;$ , yet

$$f'(x)=-\sin x\le\cos x=g(x)$$